# Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

После запуска приложение фейлится. Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Перелазил интернет, но что-то пока не нашел ответа. Вот описание:

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.service.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.service.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Вот контроллер:

```
package com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.controller;

import com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.model.User;
import com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.service.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listOfUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Вот модель:

```
package com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public @Data
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;
}
```

Вот сервис репозитория:

```
package com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.service;

import com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("UserRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Ну и сам Мейн:

```
package com.pro100denysko.app.resttest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.pro100denysko.app.resttest"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RestTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте на `RestTestApplication` докинуть `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.pro100denysko.app.resttest"})`

Comment: @Nofate ошибка поменялась на `Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration`.

Comment: Ну это естественно. Нужен EMF бин.  А вы все это поотключали в EnableAutoConfiguration. Куда Spring должен сохранять пользователей?

Comment: @Nofate У меня есть база данных пользователей. Приложение должно брать их с базы, и выводить на экран.

Comment: Но вы отключили автоконфигурирование JPA, DataSource и Hibernate.

Comment: Ну то есть либо вы полностью отдаете себя в руки Spring Boot и правите .properties файлы, либо настраиваете такие вещи сами (см. ответ).

Comment: @Nofate Я прописал application.properties 
`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rest-test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
и убрал EnableAutoConfiguration, но все равно выпадает `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку вы отключили автоконфмгурирование DataSource средствами Spring Boot, то согласно [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config) для работы с репозиториями Spring Data вам нужно сконфигурировать JPA самостоятельно:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.pro100denysko.app.resttest"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RestTestApplication {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() 
    return // тут DataSource к вашей БД
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.pro100denysko.app.resttest.model");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
  }
}
```